# Should we source control the .mocks.dart files created by build_runner for mockito

Tags: flutter, tdd, dart-null-safety

Because of *null safety* in dart, we had to update our codes test. We are using *mockito* for mocking the dependecies for the given class. As per their [docs](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/blob/master/NULL_SAFETY_README.md), we decided to use the *build_runner* method to generate Mock Classes of the dependencies. This is creating files with the extension `.mocks.dart` in the same folder as that of the test file. Since these are generate files, should we source control them, or put them the `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, that's up to you, but I would recommend putting them in `.gitignore`.

Mocks are not sensitive information like access keys or some internal configurations, so no worries from this point of view. However, storing generated files in source control could possibly lead to merge conflicts at some point while working with the team and resolving conflicts on generated files - well, that's strange and not what you want.

Since the files could be generated, there is no need to add the `*.mocks.dart` to the source control repository - you should ignore them. Just make sure that you extend your project's `ReadMe` file with documentation on how to generate these mocks so all the team members would know what's happening when tests could not be run. One disadvantage of this is that your team members would probably need to regenerate these mocks every single time before running the tests on newly pulled code, but that's a drawback you should accept with any code generation.

In my experience, I am using packages like `json_serializable`, `freezed`, generating Dart files for localizations, assets using `flutter_gen` - these also require generating files from source code (e.g. `*.g.dart` and `*.freezed.dart` ones). Those files are not stored in source control. Also, when using CI/CD tools for the project, you can just trigger the `flutter pub run build_runner build` command (or any other that generates your files) before building the code and everything should be good to go.

Comment: What about packages? We have some packages that depends on Freezed or `json_serializable`, but we still didn't find a way for the main app to generate the files for the packages, so we are currently versioning the generated files in the packages repositories. Do you know if there's any way to avoid this?

Comment: Do you have a reason why the main app should generate the files for packages? I mean, if you split the code part into a separate package, keep it separate - generate the code in the package itself. To keep the mono repo approach clean, use something like Melos where you can define your code generation scripts.

Comment: Because I don't want to version generated files. This is going to be solved in the static programming tooling that's in development, but I would like to know if it's possible to do it in current `build_runner`.